# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte XX with urllib2 urlopen()

Tags: python, urllib2, django-nonrel

I'm trying to post some data to a url, but I'm running int a python error that doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 765, in emit
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1086: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR    2011-12-09 16:58:16,664 dev_appserver.py:4096] Exception encountered handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4039, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3945, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 605, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3015, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2925, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2787, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    script_module.main()
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/djangoappengine/main/main.py", line 87, in real_main
    run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/views/debug.py", line 114, in get_traceback_html
    frames = self.get_traceback_frames()
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/views/debug.py", line 242, in get_traceback_frames
    pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader, module_name)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/views/debug.py", line 223, in _get_lines_from_file
    context_line = source[lineno].strip('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This causes the above error:

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://google.com/foo/", headers={"Accept" : "text/html"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

This does NOT cause the above error. The only difference is the url:

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://google.com/", headers={"Accept" : "text/html"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

So the problem appears to be anything anything after the domain name. Any ideas why?

Comment: That isn't your full code, quite clearly. You're doing something with that `response` which is causing an error. What are you doing with it?

Comment: Daniel, It doesn't matter what I do with the result, this is the type of error I get if there are problems with my python, not my logic. Like interpreter errors. Sorry, I'm not explaining well, but this isn't a Django error page. It is a purple error page like when I've done something the python interpreter can't understand.  Check my updates for more info.

Comment: I think the "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte XX" is a clue to why its choking. But why wouldn't urllib2.Request() be able to take in a url with like http://google.com/foo/ ?

Comment: I think you need somehing like what is explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4790654/183066) response to a similar question, that is, get the encoding from the headers and decode the contents of the page using that encoding.

Comment: What version of GAE are you using? 1.6.1 has a bug open on httplib2. Rolling back to 1.6.0 should "fix" the issue. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6567&q=1.6.1&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my problem to go away by just using urllib and not urllib2. I still don't know what caused the problem, but this workout was fine.

```
url = 'http://google.com/'
f = urllib.urlopen(url, params)
```